# Convert column with data MM/DD/YYYY varchar to date in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've found some similar questions but haven't been able to get anything to work yet. I'm very much a novice with little SQL experience.

I have a column END_DATE as Varchar(10) where all the rows follow the mm/dd/yyyy format and I would like to convert it to date. I have an empty column formatted as date if that helps. There are 36 million rows.

Comment: Why is it `VARCHAR(10)` and not `DateTime`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,YourColumn,101) FROM YourTable
```

101 is mm/dd/yyyy format.

You zany backwards americans :)

To update your existing column

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourNewColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME,YourOldColumn,101)
```

Since it appears you have invalid data, use this method to isolate it:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET YourNewColumn = CONVERT(DATETIME,YourOldColumn,101)
WHERE SomeTableKey BETWEEN ASmallCode AND ABiggerCode
```

Find a key in your table that you can use to divide up the data and try updating half the table... now halve it again and again until you find the offending data. Post the data here and we will come up with some code to allow for it.

Comment: I've tried this but I get this error: Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Then your data is not in nn/dd/yyy format after all. You need to inspect your data line by line and find the offending data. Find some kind of key in your table and narrow it down by updating only chunks of data. This is a common problem when storing dates as VARCHAR

Comment: Thanks - I had some dates that were 99/99/9999 and I think that was preventing it. After converting these to null, I was able to get it to work just fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Tick one of the answers if it helps.

Comment: To identify the offending data, If the cardinality of the source column is relatively low, you could try this: "select YourOldColumn, count(*) from YourTable group by YourOldColumn".  Even if you have 5 years worth of data and 13M rows you only need to examine 365*5 rows, starting with the first and last looking for out-lyres.

Comment: @Microsoft, if your'e listening, could you please add two (2) new functions `ERROR_ROWNUMBER()` and `ERROR_COLVALUE()` to the group for "_Retrieving Error Information_" in `TRY` `CATCH` blocks, referred to on this page: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) ?...
...And how about including the row number and the error value in the error message?

Comment: This is your best chance of having hem listen: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer connect actually has a list of enhancements that you can vote on

Answer (score 1):

I think you should convert END_DATE to DATETIME type, because you have 36 million rows and it will give a performance boost when you do not have to cast or convert it datetime with select statement.

To answer your question, you can do something like

select CAST(END_DATE AS DATETIME) FROM MyTable

Comment: Without some kind of picture format, this is not reliable.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @End_DATE VARCHAR(10);
SET @End_DATE = '12/20/2013';

SELECT CAST(@End_DATE AS DATE)

RESULT: 2013-12-20
```

Empty Column formatted as Date, I am guessing you meant to say you have DATE datatype column and you would like to update this VARCHAR(10) date to , Date datatype column you could do something like this....

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET New_End_DATE = CAST(End_DATE AS DATE)
```

### [`Working SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/42a50/1)

Comment: I've tried this before and get the same error - Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: @TZ100 Have a look at the Sql Fiddle I have added to my answer. Are you sure have data in mm/dd/yyyy format ??? fiddle seems to work fine.

Comment: I think it was because there are dates that are 99/99/9999 - After converting these to Null, was able to get it to work. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The [PARSE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) (SQL 2012) or [CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) (any version) can do the conversion for you.  Your UPDATE query will look something like one of these statements:

```
UPDATE the_table SET the_column = PARSE(end_date AS datetime2 USING 'en-US')

UPDATE the_table SET the_column = CONVERT(datetime2, end_date, 101)
```

Comment: the first one gives the error - Msg 9819, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error converting string value '99/99/9999' into data type datetime using culture 'en-us'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: secone one gives the error - Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.